# What is the reason that this RJ11 cable can't be connected to this socket?

Tags: connector, pins, telephone, plug, port

I connect one end of this RJ11 to my router's WAN port, and I connect the other end of it to a 3-pin plug, and I connect that 3-pin plug to the phone jack, but when I try to connect the RJ11 cable to the RJ11 socket, it gets stuck.

The RJ11 cable:
[image]

The 3-pin plug:

[image]

[image]

The phone jack:
[image]

But the cable can't be connected to the socket:
[image]

Other images:
[image]
[image]

What is the reason that this RJ11 cable can't be connected to this socket?

Comment: `But the cable can't be connected to the socket` ... what does that mean? ... it cannot be inserted? ... please describe the problem ... `can't do it` is too vague

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the plug does not fit into the jack.

Looks like you are trying to insert an RJ11 plug into an RJ9 jack.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a telephone over mains extender. There are only two pins of six with contacts fitted. Ethernet would need at least four of eight.

[image]

It looks dangerous, whatever it is.